# Why EOSIO using eosio.token?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio.token

When you transfered the token to another account, you can see the console log in terminal...

Like this :

```
eos@ubuntu:~$ cleos transfer eosio account_name "0.1 SYS"
executed transaction: 681e8f2153103351f3ef028d3c13963546091ec07803b8d3d97c07da58549e27  128 bytes  2180 us
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"eosio","to":"innocent.eom","quantity":"0.1000 SYS","memo":""}
#         eosio <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"eosio","to":"innocent.eom","quantity":"0.1000 SYS","memo":""}
#  innocent.eom <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"eosio","to":"innocent.eom","quantity":"0.1000 SYS","memo":""}
```

Thus i got a question. What transaction was made is only one but transfering actions are three times way. Why this happen??

Comment: The first is the real action that you called, and the second and third is just a notification to the sender and the receiver, if the sender or receiver is a contract, it can do something in it's contract.

Comment: @JimmyGuo so you mean eosio.token <= eosio.token is the real action?? And how do sender and receiver know the notification??

Comment: eosio.token is the account which EOS token's contract is deployed.